# How to reload the same values from database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database, webforms

So I'm busy with an asp.net c# quiz app where users can log in and take a quiz. The values/questions of the quiz are been taken from database, it displays and works alright but the problem is that when all questions have been answered, i have a button that says "do quiz again" on which i redirect user to the beginning page where the quiz is suppose to reload, but it simply shows nothing, (what i think is that it loops through the database just once and that's it or i might be wrong)

this been my c# code 
pageLoad()

```
MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM question WHERE category_id=" + categoryID, db.getCon());
            adp.Fill(ds);

            try
            {
                // teller = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
                lblQuestion.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();
                rbA.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString();
                rbB.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString();
                rbC.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][4].ToString();
                rbD.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][5].ToString();
                correctAnswer = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][6].ToString();
                infoQuestion = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][7].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
```

and button click

```
private void nextQuestion()
    {
        i++;
        lblQuestion.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();
        rbA.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString();
        rbB.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString();
        rbC.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][4].ToString();
        rbD.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][5].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: while returning to beginning you should set `i=0;`  also remove the `try catch(Exception)` probably you are swallowing index out of range exception with it.

Comment: We need more code. Show the code you did, it's hard to tell it like this

Comment: Please, add a code that is triggered at the end of quiz. Also, where are you setting value for variable i ?

Comment: i triggered it with a try catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Page_Load set `i=0` so it doesn't get out of range. You're not resetting it after quiz is done

Add some logging here, or a pop-up message. It's never a good idea to swallow exception like this.

```
catch (Exception)
{

}
```

Add `try-catch` in nextQuestion() so you can catch the issue when filling in next question. This way, you're doing it only on Page_Load